# Remove lines in a file where pattern only occurs once

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

I have a CSV file.  It is ordered by an identifier the first field.  The identifier in the first field can appear in either 1 or in 2 lines in the field.  I want to remove all lines in the file where the identifier only occurs once.

Example, file contains:

```
Id1,x11,x12...
Id2,x21,x22...
Id2,x23,x24...
```

In this case, I want to remove the first line because Id1 only occurs once.

Comment: Is the file sorted by the identified field or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";}{if (!ids[$1]) {ids[$1]=1;lines[$1]=$0;} else {if (ids[$1]==1) {print lines[$1]; print; ids[$1]++;} else {print;}}}'
```

When an id is encountered first, it is stored into the **ids** associative array, and the whole line is stored into **lines** associative array but not printed.

When an id is encountered twice or more, the line stored is printed and each additional lines are printed as well.

The test:

```
$ cat data.csv
Id1,x11,x12...
Id2,x21,x22...
Id2,x23,x24...

$  awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";}{if (!ids[$1]) {ids[$1]=1;lines[$1]=$0;} else {if (ids[$1]==1) {print lines[$1]; print; ids[$1]++;} else {print;}}}' data.csv
Id2,x21,x22...
Id2,x23,x24...
```

Answer (score 1):

[Jay's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275761/59699) is the general `awk` solution for unordered, but for ordered it can be simpler:

```
awk -F, '$1!=id {id=$1;pr=$0 ORS;next} {print pr $0;pr=""}'
```